# Passing parameters to GET request

Tags: rest, go, request

I cannot seem to figure how to do this in `go`.

I was following this tutorial:

https://github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest

and I can pass parameters using `Header`, which I think is a bad idea.

I am basically looking for `go` version of `python`

```
In [28]: import requests

In [29]: r = requests.get("http://localhost:8000/get_result", params={"number": 40})
```

Following is my code for my REST API:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "fmt"
)

func make_result(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fmt.Println(r)

    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    number_string := r.Form["number"][0]
    // number_string := r.Header["Number"][0] header solution
    number, err := strconv.Atoi(number_string)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, fmt.Sprint(number * 5))

}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/get_result", make_result)
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8000", nil)
}
```

I am trying to call it using this code:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"    
    "reflect"
    "github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest"

)

func main() {

    resp, body, errs := gorequest.New().
        Get("http://localhost:8000/get_result").
        Set("Number", "7").      // Changes the Header 
        Type("form").            // These two lines appear 
        Send(`{"number": 5}`).   // to be irrelevant 
        End()


    fmt.Println(errs)
    fmt.Println(resp)
    fmt.Println(body)

}
```

The above is similar to python's:

```
In [34]: r = requests.get("http://localhost:8000/get_result", headers={"Number": 7})
```

When I am using the python method (using params) to call the api, I see `/get_result?number=7 <nil> <nil>` line being printed as a part of `request object`. But am don't see it in my go version, so I must be calling it wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to use [`Param`](https://godoc.org/github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest#SuperAgent.Param) to do this.

Also the standard library's [`NewRequest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest) returns a Request struct with a member [`URL`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) that has a function [`Query`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Query) that you can use to [`Add`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.Add) parameters to your query before issuing the request.